# How can I get the "upgrade projects" wizard back if I said "no"?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

As described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/upgrading-projects-from-earlier-versions-of-visual-cpp?view=msvc-160), when you open a solution or project in a newer version of VS you get a dialog asking about updates to VS version, Windows SDK, etc.

If you choose not to upgrade, VS appears to remember this choice next time and does not ask. Is there a way to manually recall this wizard, or to make VS forget so it will ask me again next time I open the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, If you are looking for this wizard?

[image]

If so, I suggest you could try to right click the project -> Retarget Projects.

[image]